# Creating a system image on Windows 10 fails

Tags: windows, windows-10, partitioning, windows-backup

I want to make a image of my Windows 10 partition with all apps and settings, but I'm unable to do so.

I get this error when I click `Start the backup` button
[image: img1]

Before that error, I'm presented with this window, which possibly has something to do with the error
[image: img2]

C:/ is where Windows is installed, BUILDPART is partition that was already on my HP Laptop when I bought it, I guess it contains some HP's software, so I didn't touch it. There's also HPDOCS partition, which contains some documentation from HP, but it's not present as System partition in that list when I try to start the creation of system image.

I'm not sure what are these two partitions meant for, I did some research on the Internet, and some people say it's safe to format them, some say that would void the warranty...
They take up about 8GB each...

Comment: Format your drive `E:` as NTFS. Don't touch other partitions on primary hard drive if you want in a future rollback to factory restore.

Comment: No, drive (E:) is external hard drive, formatted as NTFS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message mentioned that the target is either not an NTFS drive, or it is not a fixed drive.

You commented that your *external drive* is formatted as NTFS.

An external drive is not considered a fixed drive, but a removable drive. And that's why you can't create the backup.

To solve this issue, either backup to an internal drive, or use other backup software. If you're looking for good backup software, I have good experience with VEEAM, which comes with a free version.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. I don't have any other internal drive, it's laptop, I have only a single SSD with single partition. 

Can you point me to the exact product on VEEAM website, there is a lot of different products, not sure which one I need?

Comment: Nevermind, I downloaded software named Macrium, seems to work fine

Comment: @kecman [Veeam Agent for Microsoft Windows FREE](https://www.veeam.com/windows-endpoint-server-backup-free.html)